# Android/Java - Is it necessary on android's side to request a MTU update?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, mtu

I have wrote firmware for a BLE device, and it is expecting 40 bytes when receiving a packet.

My question is: Is it necessary to receive the event "onMtuChanged()" for my android device to send more than 23 bytes? In other words, does this callback ALLOW my device to send more than 23 bytes?

Secondly, is there a way for me to internally set the MTU size within android so that I don't have to request the MTU exchange? My BLE devices disconnect after receiving data (part of a mesh network), so I have to exchange MTU requests every time I send data. It slows down transmission considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be allowed to transfer more than the default MTU, a new MTU must be negotiated. Sending larger packets without having exchanged a larger MTU is forbidden according to the specification. You can either initiate the MTU change from Android side (as you already found out) or from the peripheral side (in which case Android won't give you any callback).

If you don't like the extra roundtrip it takes to do this, why don't you just send two Write Without Response packets? That would fit 40 bytes and can be sent during a single connection event.

Comment: I can't send 2 packets as the BLE device disconnects after receiving a message to push the message through the mesh network.

Comment: Then you might simply consider modifying your firmware so you can allow multiple small packets to be received?

Answer (score 0):

This is allowed to send more than 23 bytes.

You can use the snippet：
`gatt.requestMtu(MTU);//MTU is that you want to send bytes`

A `onMtuChanged(BluetoothGatt, int, int)` callback will indicate whether this operation was successful.

If you don't exchange MTU requests every time, you should reconnect by official way, that keep `gatt` not `null` in every time you want to send bytes again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this was more of a conceptual question, I know how to exchange MTU already. Also, i'm working with 50+ nodes, so I have to make my gatt null every round.